# How do I use LINQ to count number of objects in largest group?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I use LINQ to find the count of the largest group of objects in an object collection?

As an example:

```
struct MyObject
{
    public int SomeInt;
    public int GroupInt;
}

List<MyObject> ObjectList = new List<MyOBject>();

// populate list

int LargestGroup = ObjectList.GroupBy(x => x.GroupInt).Max().Count();
```

This doesn't seem to work for me, as it resulted in an error:

> ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.

How can I correct this LINQ query (if it is wrong) or what should I look for to prevent this error if it is correct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your current query is trying to find the 'maximum group' and then subsequently retrieving that group's count. This clearly doesn't make sense; groups don't have any natural order, and there's no way for `Enumerable.Max` to know that you're interested in finding the group with the biggest *Count*.

What you probably want is:

```
int largestGroupCount = ObjectList.GroupBy(x => x.GroupInt)
                                  .Max(g => g.Count());
```

which uses the overload of [`Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535031.aspx) that "Invokes a transform function on each element of a sequence and returns the maximum Int32 value."

One could view this as similar to:

```
int largestGroupCount = ObjectList.GroupBy(x => x.GroupInt)
                                  .Select(g => g.Count()) 
                                  .Max();
```

which creates a sequence by projecting each group to its count, and then finds the maximum of *that* sequence.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what the LINQ syntax is trying to do - you helped solve the problem as well as clear up some of my understanding of LINQ.